# How to use a local git repository for a foxx application on ArangoDB

Tags: git, arangodb, foxx

Foxx supports using a github repository for applications. How can we use a local git repo or any other vendor's repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) For any other remote vendor you have the following options:

1) If it offers an url to download the file as a zip like github does e.g.:
`https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/archive/devel.zip` you can simply use this URL to install the foxx app.

`foxx-manager install <your url>.zip /test`

2) If not you can checkout the repository locally and continue with B)

B) If you have the repository locally say at the location `/Users/me/myApp` you can install it from the local file system using:

`foxx-manager install /Users/me/myApp /test`

We plan to support other git vendors directly as well in the future but it is not yet implemented.

Comment: I'm not sure how this feature has been built. Is it not possible to simply add a tab for git where you just put any well-formed git repository URI (and optionally an ssh key, etc)? If you're just using the git binary in the backend this shouldn't be too hard to implement right? For now though I'll use what you suggested.

Comment: you are right that is on your list of future improvements.